# C++ implicit conversion and universal forwarding on gcc 7.5

Tags: c++, c++17, gcc4

I am creating a library component that uses universal forwarding.
This works fine in most cases but I have encountered a case where our linux build (seeminingly) incorrectly uses a copy constructor instead of a move constructor.

I was able to reproduce this in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Tr1r33) on gcc 7.5 (same as our linux build platform) with a MVE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A 
{
    A(){}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&& other){ cout << "move A " << endl; }
};

template<class T>
struct B
{
    template<class U = T>
    B(U&& other)
    : m_a(std::forward<U>(other))
    {
        cout << "forward T into B " << endl;
    }
    T m_a;
};

B<A> foo(A a)
{
    return a;
    //return std::move(a);
}

int main() 
{    
    A a;
    auto b = foo(std::move(a));
}
```

For clarity I added the non compilable version to illustrate the problem.

Now, as far as I know I can't use (N)RVO in this case so a move is not inherently wrong but I'd rather avoid writing return move(...);
When compiling this with gcc 8.1 (or a relatively recent MSVC) it does use the move constructor without the move. So is this just a compiler problem or is there something I need to improve on my "B" struct to handle this case?

Comment: What problem is the example supposed to reproduce? The linked godbolt compiles without error.

Comment: The linked godbolt had the compiling return std::move(a); I now added the non compiling return a; hopefully that is clearer.

Comment: I recommend changing the code in the question accordingly.

Comment: Okay, done. Hopefully this shows the problem clearer.
In short, I'd like to avoid a move in my return.

Comment: This is [core issue 1579](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1579), it was [fixed for gcc 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shown program (using `return a;`) is well-formed since C++17. As such, you need a C++17 conforming compiler to compile it. C++17 support in GCC 7 was experimental (C++17 hadn't been released yet).

Using `return std::move(a);` is well-formed since C++11, and such should work with much older compilers.

---

Regarding the different wording that makes it work in C++17:

C++14 (draft):

> [class.copy]
>
> **When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met**, but not for an exception-declaration, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, or when the expression in a return statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of t    (3.1)
> he innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.
>
> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object ...
>
> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (**other than a function** or catch-clause **parameter**)

C++17 (draft):

> [class.copy.elision]
>
> An implicitly movable entity is a variable of automatic storage duration that is either a non-volatile object or an rvalue reference to a non-volatile object type. In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation is first considered before attempting a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a return ([stmt.return]) or co_­return ([stmt.return.coroutine]) statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an implicitly movable entity declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, or

In short, the automatic move instead of copy from lvalue in return statement rule used to be coupled with the copy/move elision rule which doesn't apply to function parameters. Now, they have been decoupled and the former applies explicitly to function parameters as well.